# After intput of data, redirect to a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to redirect to a different page after details have been submitted.
I have tried the commented-out code. It does re-direct BUT then doesn't take in the data.
When I take comment it out, it doesn't redirect but it takes in the data.
I hope I explained this properly.

Any ideas?

```
      <script>
        var curatio = {};
        curatio.webdb = {};
        curatio.webdb.db = null;

        curatio.webdb.open = function() {
            var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
            curatio.webdb.db = openDatabase("Curatio", "1.0", "Todo manager", dbSize);
        }

    curatio.webdb.createTable = function() {
        var db = curatio.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
                       tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weight(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT, added_on DATETIME, date TEXT, note TEXT )", []);
                       });
    }

    curatio.webdb.addTodo = function(todoText) {
        var db = curatio.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function(tx){
                       var addedOn = new Date();
                       var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
                       var note = document.getElementById("note").value;
                       tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO weight(todo, added_on, date, note) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
                                     [todoText, addedOn, date, note],
                                     curatio.webdb.onSuccess,
                                     curatio.webdb.onError);
                       });
    }

    curatio.webdb.onError = function(tx, e) {
        alert("There has been an error: " + e.message);
    }

    curatio.webdb.onSuccess = function(tx, r) {
        // re-render the data.
        curatio.webdb.getAllTodoItems(loadTodoItems);
    }


    curatio.webdb.getAllTodoItems = function(renderFunc) {
        var db = curatio.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
                       tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM weight", [], renderFunc,
                                     curatio.webdb.onError);
                       });
    }

    curatio.webdb.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        var db = curatio.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function(tx){
                       tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM weight WHERE ID=?", [id],
                                     curatio.webdb.onSuccess,
                                     curatio.webdb.onError);
                       });
    }

    function loadTodoItems(tx, rs) {
        var rowOutput = "";
        var todoItems = document.getElementById("todoItems");
        for (var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
            rowOutput += renderTodo(rs.rows.item(i));
        }

        todoItems.innerHTML = rowOutput;
    }

    function renderTodo(row) {
        return "<li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Weight:&nbsp;" + row.todo  + "&nbsp;kg&nbsp;" + "<br />" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date:&nbsp;" + row.date + "<br />" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Note:&nbsp;" + row.note + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href='javascript:void(0);'  onclick='curatio.webdb.deleteTodo(" + row.ID +");'>Delete</a>]</li>";
    }

    function init() {
        curatio.webdb.open();
        curatio.webdb.createTable();
        curatio.webdb.getAllTodoItems(loadTodoItems);
    }

    function addTodo() {
        var todo = document.getElementById("todo");
        curatio.webdb.addTodo(todo.value);
        todo.value = "";
        alert("Your weight has been added");
        //window.location = 'users.html'
        //location.href="users.html";
    }


    </script>
```

...
...

```
<form type="post" onsubmit="addTodo(); return false;">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="todo">
                Weight
            </label>
            <input name="" id="todo" placeholder="75" value="" type="text">
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="date">
                    Date
                </label>
                <input name="" id="date" placeholder="" value="" type="date">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="note">
                    Notes
                </label>
                <input name="" id="note" placeholder="short note"></input>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true"/>

        <a rel="external" data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="users.html">
            Cancel
        </a>
        </form>
```

Comment: What's `curatio.webdb.addTodo`? Does it have the option of providing a callback?

Comment: Andy, I added the full script. Hope it helps.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [promises](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around!
Give the DB a second or two to update - and THEN redirect
This works for me:

```
function addTodo() {
    var todo = document.getElementById("todo");
    curatio.webdb.addTodo(todo.value);
    todo.value = "";
    alert("Your weight has been added");
    setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "users.html"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't however seem to work on mobile devices :(

Comment: I cleared my mobile web history and it actually works perfectly! Reloaded and now it works 100%

Answer (score 0):

http is a stateless, you have to carry your parameter to your other page by using query string 
for example 
window.location.href =   "users.html?myVlue=9"
and then you have process myvalue in your other page

I hope this helpful

Comment: Hi Besher. Sorry to be a bit dumb on this, but could you be more specific? How would I do what you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Change your onsubmit to return the function and not false...then in your JS function simply return false to halt submission of the form or true to submit the form as normal. Here is a short example of what I mean

```
<script>
    function validateForm(){
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x==null || x==""){
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `window.opener` to send your data from one page to another. Though this will open the page in a new window. There are lots of pages on this, try googling `window.opener`.
Do let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Raza, are you suggesting window.opener.document.location("users.htm");

Comment: Not exactly, you can use `window.opener.variableName = yourVariableWithData` to pass the data which you want to the other page.
In the other page use `newVariableForData = window.opener.variableName`
This method is very easy to implement. I hope this helps you.
FYI- This works in Android tablets, but in IOS it wont work.